# Проблема с background при изменении окна браузера

Tags: css, css3

При сужении окна или при добавлении в дом дерево элемента который выше окна браузера появляется скрол (что логично) и при прокрутке на месте бэкграунда белая пропасть, которая исчезает при перезагрузке страницы. Можно ли этого избежать (то есть хотелось бы в таких случаях чтобы бэкграунд автоматически заполнил пробел)

код стиля фона

```
.bg_image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("../assets/img/bground_image.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

визуализация проблемы в картинке при сужении окна сфлоаченный элемент уходит вниз и образуется белое пятно[image: при сужении окна сфлоаченный элемент уходит вниз и образуется белое пятно]

Answer (score 1):

В идеале конечно видеть весь код, но постараюсь ответить так.

Высота блока установлена в 100vh. Соответственно больше чем высота экрана блок никак не станет. Соответственно элементы которые не помещаются в эту высоту - вылезают наружу.

Если допустимо чтобы этот блок с фоном растягивался на высоту большую чем 100vh, то замените

`height: 100vh;` на `min-height: 100vh;`

Так же не забывайте о "распорке" когда используете флоаты. На родителя в котором лежат зафлоаченые блоки нужно повесить класс `.clearfix`

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Если же нужно чтобы блок с фоном не превышал высоту экрана, тогда остаётся лишь обрезать элементы, которые в него не помещаются. Тут в помощь `overflow: hidden;` на этот самый блок c фоном.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно тут три решения:

1. вы можете задать `padding-bottom: 200px;` (например и тогда картинка увеличится и элемент не вылезет),В общем то если ставите fixed или absolute это значит элемент будет декоративен,т.е высчитать высоту без js не реально чтобы подстроить(возможно манипуляции в `css(calc())`). И поставить overflow-y: hidden; где y вертикаль.
2. зафлоаченные блоки выпадают из контейнера(им нужно задать высоту или clearfix)
3. Средствами js просчитывается высота окна и на основе этого увеличивается padding, погуглите думаю найдете.

вот пример вашей проблемы:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/OcmdOiOAdSMX81qG?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавленние в класс с фоном `overflow-y: scroll;`  и ненавязчивая кастомизация скроллбара

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 3px; height: 3px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 40px; background-color: #327389; border-radius: 3px;}
```